# Область применения std::weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

`std::weak_ptr` может быть создан из `std::shared_ptr`, но у меня такой вопрос. `weak_ptr` может вернуть информацию про умный указатель, точнее висячий он или нет. 
Разве умные указатели  не были созданы для того, чтобы предотвратить ситуации висячих указателей? 
В чем смысл создавать `std::shared_ptr`, чтобы с него делать еще один `std::weak_ptr`, которым потом можно узнать или счетчик ссылок с блоке контроля умного указателя равен нулю?

Где это можно использовать? Как может `std::weak_ptr` и информация которую он несет, быть полезной на практике?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::weak_ptr` не является владельцем объекта, и призван решать проблему перекрестных ссылок.

Разберем такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

//Имеется класс компонента
struct Component: 
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<Component>
{   //Который содержит умные указатели на
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>> children;//дочерние компоненты
    std::shared_ptr<Component> parent;//и на родителя

    void add(std::shared_ptr<Component> v) 
    {
        children.push_back(std::move(v));
        children.back()->parent = shared_from_this();
    }
    Component()
    { 
        std::cout << "Component::Component()" << std::endl; 
    }
    ~Component() 
    { 
        std::cout << "Component::~Component()" << std::endl; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Component> component1 = std::make_shared<Component>();
    std::shared_ptr<Component> component2 = std::make_shared<Component>();
    component1->add(std::move(component2));
}
```

Если [запустить данный код](https://rextester.com/WRQTLR2339), то увидим, что после выхода из main деструкторы объектов вызваны не были, т.е. объекты не уничтожились. Почему?

Всё дело в том, что объекты, которыми владеют `std::shared_ptr` уничтожаются когда не остается владельцев (тех самых `shared_ptr`). В нашем же коде, родительский компонент владеет дочерним, а дочерний компонент содержит `shared_ptr` на родительский компонент, т.е. владеет родительским компонентом. Таким образом, они владеют друг другом, и не дают уничтожится друг другу. Это и есть перекрестные ссылки.

`std::weak_ptr` является умным указателем, который не владеет объектом.

Если в вышеуказанном коде поменять тип parent на `std::weak_ptr`, то родительский компонент теперь будет являться владельцем дочерних компонентов, а дочерние компоненты перестанут быть владельцами родительского. Соответственно, они не будут "держать друг друга за руки", и [уничтожатся при выходе из main](https://rextester.com/PME70721).

Answer (score 0):

Иногда мы хотим чтобы объект удалился как можно быстрее, а не висел пока живы все его владельцы. Например когда объект владеет большим куском памяти, или каким-то системным ресурсом.

```
struct X {
  char data[100500];
};

std::shared_ptr<X> sp(new X);
```

Мы можем закинуть ссылку на этот объект в много разных мест

```
AddTimer(3h, [wp = std::weak_ptr<X>(sp)]{
    if (auto p = wp.lock()) {...};
});
```

и если мы не будем использовать `weak_ptr`, то эти объекты будут висеть минимум по 3 часа.

(Тут надо отметить что мы также не можем использовать `make_shared` т.к. тогда там будет выделен один большой блок памяти, который будет жить до последнего `weak_ptr`.)

Также `weak_ptr` позволяет бороться с утечками из-за циклических зависимостей.